# Import firebase firestore from CDN JS not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, import, cdn

I am importing Firebase Firestore from CDN to run on a local server. I imported it as the documentation says, right here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup

My code :

```
  import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-auth.js';
import { firestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-firestore.js'
```

The problem:
Firebase app and firebase auth are imported and work perfectly however, Firestore is not being imported. I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-firestore.js' does not provide an export named 'firestore'
```

This is my first web project using firebase and I dont know how to move forward. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated by this newbie. If you need anymore information let me know, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the source has been deprecated. Cause the explanation written like this, from this source https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup#from-the-cdn

> For most Firebase Web apps we strongly recommend using SDK version 9 via npm.

I found two ways, in version 8 you can still use that way.

```
<body>
    <!-- Insert this script at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</body>
```

But if you want use in version 9, you have to use npm.

```
npm install firebase@9.4.1 --save

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

You can visit: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9

Hopefully this can help you.

Answer (score 4):

One way to import is, first create a file called **firebase.js** and paste this code :

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js";  
import { getFirestore, getDocs, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-firestore.js";

//add your credentials from firebase project
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR-apiKey-nCVgNHJXTs",
  authDomain: "YOUR-authDomain.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "YOUR-projectId-fb",
  storageBucket: "YOUR-storageBucket-fb.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR-messagingSenderId",
  appId: "YOUR-appId-web:11c8d54e0"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

//create your custom method
export const getWolfs = () => {
  return getDocs(collection(db, "yourNameCollection"));
};
```

Now, you can create a new file called **main.js** and paste this code:

```
import { getWolfs } from './firebase.js';

//suppose you want to display the list of wolves in the browser console
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async (e) => {
    const querySnapshot = await getWolfs();
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
    });
});
```

Finally create the html file **index.html** and paste this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>firebase</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>wolves</h2>
        <!--main app-->
        <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sample project:

[image: proyecto-lobo]

That is all, i hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Have you type this in script tag

```
<body>
  <script type="module">
    // ...

    // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      // ...
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</body>
```

`type=module` ?

Comment: Yes I did, I have JS in another file, here's the script tag `<script type="module" src="../JS/fileSignUpFinal.js"></script>`

Comment: I have added new answer, and should be solved, i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this issue similar with you

```
import { function } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-SERVICE.js'

//Example
import { function } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-firestore.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does not provide an export named 'firestore' but

```
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.n.n/firebase-firestore.js";
const firestore = getFirestore();
console.log(firestore);
```

does.

See: [getFirestore()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getfirestore)

Answer (score 0):

if none of those above worked due to some global error in newer versions of angular try this CDN's with compat at the end.

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

these are worked for me to generate token in console.