# Can not connect to firebase authentication browser module

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Hey everyone I am learning firebase phone authentication in web app. I have an error that I can not find the solution. I imported the browser module for firebase authentication as show in the first picture but when I checked the console I got an error that said my app not connected to firebase authentication module. How can I solve this problem ?
[Import from firebase browser module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT0gm.png)

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HhF0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error, but I was successful in connecting to the authentication module that can run, which is the point of the matter.

Steps:

> Enable Phone Number sign-in for your Firebase project https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#enable-phone-number-sign-in-for-your-firebase-project

> Initialize Firebase

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app.js";


  // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "A#######YOUR#API#KEY#BUT#RESPONSE##SUCCESSFULL###############",
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

> Testing connection with the authentication module

```
  // TEST MODULE AUTH
  const auth = getAuth();
  console.log("LOADED FIREBASE-AUTH", auth);
  // overwrite DOM with the version used from response CDN
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = auth.config.sdkClientVersion;
```

Some observations:

> phoneAuth => make sure to import RecaptchaVerifier
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha

```
`import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-auth.js";`
```

> Well what I can deduce from the error, is as it says: internet disconnected.
> It may also be related, here: Import firebase firestore from CDN JS not working [Import firebase firestore from CDN JS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732003/import-firebase-firestore-from-cdn-js-not-working).

I hope to be helpful!. Or can you provide more details if the error continues.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Add a container for reCaptcha -->
    <button id="sign-in-button">sign-in-button</button>

    <p id="content">SHOW INFO CONNEXION AUTH</p>

    <script type="module">
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app.js";
      import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-auth.js";

      // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "A#######YOUR#API#KEY#BUT#RESPONSE##SUCCESSFULL###############",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      // TEST MODULE AUTH
      const auth = getAuth();
      console.log("LOADED FIREBASE-AUTH", auth);
      // overwrite DOM with the version used from response CDN
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = auth.config.sdkClientVersion;

      // phoneAuth => make sure to import RecaptchaVerifier
      // Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        "sign-in-button",
        {
          size: "invisible",
          callback: (response) => {
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
            // onSignInSubmit();
            // ...
          },
        },
        auth
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem was solved by itself, I never know either what was the real problem or how it just disappear. My code actually look the same as your answer. Thank you for giving your time to anwer.